# How to stop CodeIgniter from quoting my table

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter, query-builder

Okay, this may be silly, but i can't make CI to stop quoting my table. I use this code in my model :

```
$oracle->select('id',FALSE);
$oracle->from('ms_item');
```

That code will result Select statement as follow:

```
SELECT id FROM "ms_item"
```

The problem is, Oracle can't find the table when it have quotes or double quotes. The CI said that second parameter in select() will remove any quote generated by Query Builder, but i don't know how to remove the quote generated by from(), please help...

Thank you...

For note, i'm using Oracle 11g and oci8_11g.dll

Comment: `$oracle->from(REPLACE(ms_item, '"', '\"') AS  ms_item)`

Comment: Try writing the table name in upper case.  $oracle->from('MS_ITEM');

Comment: Lol, thank you @BobC , it worked! I'm so silly that i haven't tried that possibility.

Comment: When a table is created, unless you quote it, it will be stored as an uppercase table name. When you are quoting it ( as CI wants to do), it's performing a case sensitive match

Comment: @BobC post your comment as an answer so that 'Shira Ishikawa' can accept it. this will help others with a similar question to find the answer quickly.

Comment: @Rifky. Good idea. Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing the table name in upper case.

```
$oracle->from('MS_ITEM');
```

When a table is created, unless you quote it, it will be stored as an uppercase table name. When you are quoting it ( as CI wants to do), it's performing a case sensitive match